# Different versions for different countries playstore?

Tags: google-play, google-developers-console

Can I publish different versions of my app for different countries?
Its functionality has to change if a user is from USA or from Israel for example.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

There is concept of multiple apk's https://developer.android.com/google/play/publishing/multiple-apks.html unfortunately it cannot be customized to country specific...

**Option 1** - Release multiple projects e.g. com.XXX.USA com.XXX.IND com.XXX.UK etc and release each app only to that specific country.

**Option 2** -  Modify your program to take input from user as country and change application flow based on country selected.